# Ошибка в логах на регистрацию приемника

Tags: android, android-studio

При отправке данных на сервер, появляется ошибка:

> android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.androidtutorialpoint.androidlogin.FormSendSroch has leaked IntentReceiver com.androidtutorialpoint.androidlogin.NetworkStateChecker@a6606708 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

ругается на данную строчку в внутри метода onCreate() MainActivity:

```
 registerReceiver(new NetworkStateChecker(), new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

При этом данные отправляются нормально!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы регистрируете приёмник сообщений, но не отписываетесь от него. Это может вести к утечкам памяти, о чём вам и сообщается.

Вынесите ваш ресивер в переменную уровня активити и в методе `onDestroy` отпишитесь:

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new NetworkStateChecker()

public void onDestroy(){
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```